# HMABM Relationship Via Checkboxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to allow a `user` who created a `wiki` add collaborators on the `wiki#edit` page.

I have this in my `schema.rb` to create a join table for `collaborators`:

```
  create_table "collaborators", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "wiki_id"
  end
```

Yet in my initial migration I did add indices for both `user` and `wiki` ids:

```
class CreateCollaborators < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :collaborators do |t|
      t.integer :user_id, array: true, default: []
      t.integer :wiki_id
    end

    add_index :users, :id, unique: true
    add_index :wikis, :id, unique: true
  end
end
```

I am using this erb on my `wikis#edit` page to try to generate a list of potential collaborators (loosely following [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast) Railcast):

```
  <% if @wiki.private? %>
    <%= f.label :collaborators, class: 'checkbox' %>
    <%= @users.each do |user| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "wiki[user_ids][]", user.id, @wiki.collaborators.include?(user.id) %>
      <%= user.name %><br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Right now I am getting an error on the indicated line in my `wikis_controller` saying `uninitialized constant WikisController::Collaborator`:

```
class WikisController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
      @users = User.all
      collaborators = Collaborator.all   <<<<<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
   end
```

I have created a blank `collaborators_controller`, but as the code all takes place in the `wikis#edit` page, I wouldn't know what to put in it.

Can anyone help me do this?  I might be approaching it in the wrong way...

Comment: Do you have an `app/models/collaborator.rb` file?

Comment: No, I tried implementing a `has_many` through relationship for `users` and `wikis` but kept getting weird syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

habtm relationships are for simple join tables without a model. You can't call Collaborator because a model does not exist for the join table which is giving you the error.

If you need a model, you can switch to has_many :through relationship and create a collaborator model. In a has_many :through, your collaborators table will need to have a primary key / id column, unlike a pure join table.

Otherwise keeping with habtm you can call associations as such:

```
# Check if associated users include user
@wiki.users.include?(user)

# Get all users associated with wiki
wiki.users

# Get all wikis associated with user
user.wikis
```

Since you didn't use rails naming convention for join tables, in your models you will need to specify the join table like:

```
# models/wiki.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :users,  :join_table => :collaborators

# models/user.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :wikis,  :join_table => :collaborators
```

Comment: This was so immensely helpful!  Thank you!